# "Mutable variable is accessible from closure" in a function passed to Array.prototype.every

Tags: javascript, closures, webstorm

Code will speak more plainly than I will:

```
var candidateIndex = 0;
var minValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;
topArray.every(function(element, index) {
    if (element.innerArray && element.innerArray.length < minValue) {
        minValue = element.innerArray.length;
        candidateIndex = index;
        if (minValue == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

// ... use minValue and candidateIndex
```

What this is doing is going through the `topArray`, and finding either the first member of that array that has an `innerArray` of length 0, otherwise finding the one that has the smallest length `innerArray`.  It's working fine, but the checker that I have accurately reports "Mutable variable is accessible from closure."

I see that that's usually a bad thing, particularly with asynchronous code.  I've looked through [How to avoid access mutable variable from closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813463/how-to-avoid-access-mutable-variable-from-closure?rq=1) and [accessing mutable variable in an event closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218075/accessing-mutable-variable-in-an-event-closure), and understand that in those cases, the anonymous function is asynchronous, and it's desirable to store the state of the mutable variable at the time, but in my case, I *want* the synchronous anonymous function I invoke to change the variable.

In this case, the warning that I'm getting is wrong, and I should just ignore it, right?  Outside of using a `for` loop instead of `every`, is there any way to get the functionality I want without the warning occuring?

**Update:** for what it's worth, the warning does seem to be coming from my WebStorm IDE itself, instead of any of the analysis tool plugins.

Comment: What tool is reporting that issue?

Comment: Would you still receive the warning if you stored those tracking variables on the function itself? And is `this` set to the function before calling it inside `every`? That seems like a lot of confusing code to avoid a warning. My take: ignore the warning.

Comment: @Scott: Hm, actually I'm getting that message from neither tool (in their online versions). Could you investigate, please?

Comment: ^^ I just get "Use === to compare to zero", in `minValue == 0`; good advice, but no other warnings.

Comment: @elclanrs Same here. I suspect the warning is from WebStorm.

Comment: @David I'm all for ignoring the warning, but wanted a sanity check before saying "meh. It's a false positive."

Comment: @David that's entirely possible, and would explain why I didn't see any other tool name while looking into it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having gotten confirmation from the comments above that this warning is basically a false positive, I modified the code to ignore the warning message:

```
topArray.every(function(element, index) {
    //noinspection JSReferencingMutableVariableFromClosure
    if (element.innerArray && element.innerArray.length < minValue) {
        minValue = element.innerArray.length;
        candidateIndex = index;
        //noinspection JSReferencingMutableVariableFromClosure
        if (minValue == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

(The warning only triggers when comparing the value, as opposed to when setting it.)

I'm eager to hear any other answers, but if I don't, I'll accept this answer in about a week.